# Profile image is not getting saved in Database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am doing one project on djano-web fromework. Something weird things happen while submitting django forms.Everything is  getting saved  accept ***profile image*** in db though form is Valid.

views.py :

```
class EmployeeEditProfile(CommonViewMixin, View):
  template_name = 'edit_employee.html'
  authorization = [authorize_employee]
  user_personal_form = UserPersonalDetailForm
  user_details_form = OrganisationUserDetailsForm
  user_profile_form = OrganisationUserProfileDetailsForm
  @transaction.atomic() 
  def non_ajax_post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user_personal_form = self.user_personal_form(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    user_details_form = self.user_details_form(request.POST, instance=request.user.organisation_user.user_details)
    user_profile_form = self.user_profile_form(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=request.user.organisation_user)
    if user_details_form.is_valid() and user_personal_form.is_valid() and user_profile_form.is_valid():
        user_personal_form.save()
        user_detail = user_details_form.save()
        request.user.organisation_user.user_details = user_detail
        request.user.organisation_user.save()
        user_profile_form.save()
        request.session['user_form_saved'] = True
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
    else:
        print user_details_form.errors
        print user_personal_form.errors
        context = kwargs
        context.update({'user_personal_form': user_personal_form, 'user_details_form': user_details_form, 'user_profile_form':user_profile_form})
        return self.response_class(template='edit_employee.html',request=request,
                                   context=context)
```

models for UserProfileDetails :models.py

```
class OrganisationUserProfileDetails(models.Model):
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', null=True, blank=True, default='default_images/profile_pic')
    organisation_user = models.OneToOneField(OrganisationUser, related_name='profile_details')
```

forms.py :

```
class OrganisationUserProfileDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrganisationUserProfileDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['profile_image'].label_from_instance = lambda obj: '%s' %(obj.name)

    class Meta:
        model = OrganisationUserProfileDetails
        fields = ('profile_image',)
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store `organisation_user` as well .

Try this :

```
newproject = user_profile_form.save(commit=False) 
newproject.profile_image = request.FILES['profile_image'] 
newproject.organisation_user = request.user.organisation_user
newproject.save()
```

Comment: Still its not working even on saving organisation_user .

Comment: I have changed views.py little bit , please have a look.

Comment: @Arya is `default='default_images/profile_pic'` image ? i think if its image then it should end with image type extension.

Comment: Still its not saving  on changing default value.

Comment: hmm. Time to debug. put prints in your code for displaying POST data . check , you are getting file or not .like `print request.POST` .

Comment: Its printing  : <QueryDict: {u'username': [u'upender_employee4'], u'first_name': [u'ewsdsd'], u'last_name': [u'zxczxc'], u'dob': [u'03/19/1990'], u'mobile_number': [u'9738438841'], u'submit': [u''], u'address': [u'zxxzczxczx'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'6Gq0K7Ge61A0rLTxurXwrBiFgh1hzCKZ'], u'email': [u'admin@admin.com']}>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49728/discussion-between-priyank-patel-and-arya)

Comment: but image name is not coming.